# Edit height rich:editor tag

Tags: css, jsf, richfaces, jboss-seam

I use jsf, richfaces version:v.3.3.1.GA. I want to reduce height style of rich:editor tag (use tinyMCE) but it's not change.

```
<rich:editor id="transactionResult" style="height: 10px;" height="10"
    value="#{transactionsHome.instance.transactionResult}"
    theme="simple" viewMode="visual">
</rich:editor>
```

[image]
[image]
How can i change height or other style of rich:editor tag ?

Answer (score 0):

Use important to override the style.

```
style="height: 10px !important;"
```

For highlighted classes, add the following into your CSS:

```
.mceLayout {
height: 10px;
}
```

And for iframe:

```
#iframeID {
 height: 20px;
}
```

Replace `iframeID` with your iframe id.

Comment: i try this but not change